# How to define unchecked value to checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to set a default value for 'unchecked', but is not working. I wanted it. If checked stores = 'Yes', if unchecked stores = 'No'. I do not know why not be working. The inputs in database are inserted always with value 'Yes'. Even though they checked or unchecked.

```
<input type="hidden" name="imagem" value="no" />
<input id="imagem" type="checkbox" value="yes" >Imagem<br />

<input type="hidden" name="som" value="no" />
<input id="som" type="checkbox" value="yes" >Som<br />

<input type="hidden" name="animacao" value="no" />
<input id="animacao" type="checkbox" value="yes" >Animação<br />


<button type="button" id="enviar">Cadastrar</button><br />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#enviar" ).click(function() {
            var vjson = {};
            $( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
                vjson[$( this ).attr("id")] = $( this ).val();
            });
             // console.log(JSON.stringify(vjson));
              $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/testeform', { json: JSON.stringify(vjson), email : vjson.email}, 
                    function(returnedData){
                         console.log(returnedData);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the jquery code??

Comment: The default value will be the one specified in the value parameter. In your case, you have specified it as "yes". Unless you modify the value, it will remain so.

Comment: The hidden input and the checkbox have nothing in common.... What are you expecting to happen exactly?

Answer (score 1):

First

```
vjson[$( this ).attr("id")] = $( this ).val();
```

Since your checkboxes have no `id` attributes your value for that input when iterated over is going to be set to a property named `"undefined"`.

You can check to see if the checkbox is checked, if it is use the checkbox value, if it isn't get the hidden input by using the id selector

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function() {
   vjson[this.name] = $(this).is(":checked") ? this.value : $( "#"+this.name ).val();
});
```

Of course you could just use radio buttons. If you give them the same name, only one can be checked at a time. Then just use the [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to get the right one and get its value:

```
<input type="radio" name="som" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="som" value="yes">

var value = $("input[name=som]:checked").val();
```

Or you can just use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to have jQuery find all the values of a form and put them into a name/value pair query, or array of values. And if you have to send it as a JSON text then just convert either one to JSON.

Demo

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var data = $("form").serializeArray();
  data = data.reduce(function(values,item){
    values[item.name]=item.value;
    return values;
  },{})
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="imagem" value="no" />
  <input type="radio" name="imagem" value="yes">Imagem
  <br />

  <input type="radio" name="som" value="no" />
  <input type="radio" name="som" value="yes">Som
  <br />

  <input type="radio" name="animacao" value="no" />
  <input type="radio" name="animacao" value="yes">Animação
  <br />
</form>
<button>Send</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this one help you

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
           function check() {

               $(document).ready(function () {

                   if($("#ContentPlaceHolder1_chk_boothid").prop('checked') == true)
                   {
                       $('input[type=checkbox][id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_chk_booth_]').each(function () { this.checked = true; });

                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       $('input[type=checkbox][id*=ContentPlaceHolder1_chk_booth_]').each(function () { this.checked = false; });

                   }
               });
           }
                   </script>
```

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the markup in the question.